# Asking for input twice with if statements in C

Tags: c, if-statement, scanf

My code asks for input twice. I know that's because of the two `scanf()` calls, but I don't know how I could get rid of one of the calls in order to make it only ask for input once. I need to check to make sure the input is a number and if it is a number then make sure it's between 0 and 90.

```
printf("Hello! Let's compute the escape velocity of a baseball!\n");
printf("Please supply the angle of travel, in degrees: ");
scanf(" %lf", &angleTravel);
    if (scanf(" %lf", &angleTravel) != 1){
        printf("Please enter a number.");
        return(0);}
    if ((angleTravel > 90) || (angleTravel < 0)){ 
        printf("Please try again with an angle between 0 and 90.\n");
        return(0);}
radianTravel = angleTravel * (M_PI / 180.0); 
printf("The angle you supplied is %lf degrees, or %lf radians\n",       angleTravel, radianTravel);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could introduce a variable `matches` to store `scanf`'s result:

```
int matches = scanf(" %lf", &angleTravel);
```

and then check for `matches` in the if-clause's condition:

```
if (matches != 1){
```

Comment: The note on `return` seems preachy and out of place. It really has nothing to do with the OP's question, and whether to use parentheses with `return` is really just a matter of style/opinion.

Comment: @Caleb Never thought about the "style" part... I just had in mind she/he might be taught to use parantheses and not know its background. Will update accordingly.

Comment: If `matches == EOF`, not much use in asking again.  Recommend returning `matches`.

Answer (score 0):

You could just remove the first scanf statement. You don't need the first scanf statement.

When you run code like

```
if(f(x)==1)
{
    /*stuff*/
}
```

The code will execute the function f (or in you case, scanf), before making the comparison.